# How to turn off auto spell checking in QtCreator?

Tags: qt-creator, spell-checking

I'm currently using QtCreator 2.0, it seems that an auto spell checking feature is enabled by default, you known, sometimes it's really annoying. So I looked around in the options, but find no switcher exists for me to turn it off. How can I disable it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is indicating that it does a spell check?  Highlighting, auto-correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that it is doing spell-check?

If you are referring to the green underlining it may have to do with unused variables, which will be underlined until they are actually used.

If you are referring to the red underlining it has to do with syntax issues.

Comment: Yes, I made the mistake, they are unused variables as you said.